# Need commentary on what this Map.ofSeq signature means

Tags: f#

Can anyone please breakdown what this method signature means?

```
/// Returns a new map made from the given bindings.
/// elements: The input sequence of key/value pairs.
val ofSeq : elements:seq<'Key * 'T> -> Map<'Key,'T> when 'Key : comparison
```

Here is how it's used:

```
let grid = [ for i in 0..8 -> (i, true) ] |> Map.ofSeq
```

Specifically, can some one break this method signature into segments and explain the function of each segment?

NOTE:

I am new to F# and really do want to understand the low level details of the language.

Comment: Maybe easier to look at an example?

Comment: Hi Foggy. I updated the post.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I badly know English. I meant that it is easier to understand what is happening with an example. I'll try it -  * is a tuple of 2 elements. In your example - (i, true). Next - Seq<'key * 'T> - a sequence of tuples - [ for I in 0..8 -> (i, true) ]. This part is clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val ofSeq : elements : seq<'Key * 'T> -> Map<'Key,'T> when 'Key : comparison
```

Let's break it down.  First of all, the presence of arrows means it's a function.

Each arrow says, simplistically speaking, that when I give it something of the type on the left, I get the thing on the right.  Note that F# supports curried arguments, that means I can supply arguments one at a time, in the process returning functions with progressively fewer arguments.

In this case, your function only takes only one argument.

Your argument `elements` is of type `seq<'Key * 'T>`.  That is a sequence of tuples of two generic types: `'Key'` and `'T'`.

When I supply this function with something of type `seq<'Key * 'T>`, it is telling me that it will return a `Map<'Key,'T>`.  That is a Map which has keys of type `'Key` and values of type `'T`.

Finally you have a type constraint `when 'Key : comparison` this restricts the generic type `'Key` to be something which supports comparison, i.e. a type which implements the `IComparable` interface.  This type constraint is required because the Map is implemented using a binary tree which uses comparsion for its concept of ordering.